# TFS WIQL Query with like condition

Tags: tfs, wiql

I need to write a WIQL query on TFS 2018 with a like condition in the field IterationPath like this:

```
SELECT
        [System.Id],
        [System.WorkItemType],
        [System.Title],
        [System.State],
        [System.AreaPath],
        [System.IterationPath]
FROM workitems
WHERE
        [System.TeamProject] = @project
        and [System.IterationPath] LIKE '%MY ITERATION NAME%' 
ORDER BY [System.IterationPath] ASC
```

but I receive the error:

> Expecting comparison operator. The error is caused by «LIKE».

How I have to write the query?

Comment: I tried also with the operator contains but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The valid operators for Iteration Path are:

[image]

So you can't use `Like` (there is no Like operator in WIQL at all) or `Contains`.

The closest valid operator is `Under`, if all the iterations are under one parent you will get them all.

More info you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax).